# py2app bundles system MacOSX python 2.7 instead of python 3

Tags: python-3.x, py2app

I'm using py2app 0.18 (I can't seem to pip install 0.19) with python3. No matter what I try (from researching answers on SO) the executable 'my-build-dir'/dist/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python' starts up the system python 2.7 instead of the python 3 that I used to make the app eg

```
python3.7 setup-app.py py2app
```

where my setup-app.py file is below. Is there *any* way to force python3 to be included in app bundle rather than system python 2? Thanks!

```
# coding: utf-8
# Copyright (c) Tech-X Corporation

import os
import sys
import platform

from setuptools import setup


OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile': './docs/source/images/logo.icns'
}

setup(
    app=['Chemistream.py'],
    # !!!!!!!!! Check MANIFEST.in file !!!!!!!!
    data_files = [
        'chemistream',
        'package_data',
        'eggs',
        'chemistream.sh',
        'Chemistream-osx.sh',
        'setup.py',
        'Python-3.6.2.pkg',
        'node-v10.15.3.pkg',
        'README.txt',
        'requirements.txt',
        'docs',
        'build/sphinx/html'
    ],
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=["py2app"]
    # install_requires=["python==3.6"] # This did not work Mar/18/2019
)
```

Comment: Sounds like a PATH issue. What are you using to mange python versions?

Comment: I install python3 from a mac pkg installer. (I've tried homebrew as well and it doesn't seem to make difference). The python3 I'm using points to the installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3. Unless py2app somehow is looking for certain paths to be set?

Comment: Just to minimize confusion, my original post lists python 3.7 and my comment above says 3.6. I'm trying different things as I debug, but the version of python3 doesn't matter. The key issue is that py2app doesn't bundle *anything* other than the system 2.7 python

Comment: I believe I may have found the issue. In addition to the python2 and 3 links in /usr/local/bin there was a /usr/bin/Python pointing to the system 2.7 that py2app was finding (and it wasn't clear this was happening). I've removed the /usr/bin/Python and made a soft link for /usr/local/bin/Python to the 3.6.2 I want in my app bundle. This *seems* to now be working. Its curious, all of the python 'Framework' components in the app were named '3.6' but the binary was stubbornly remaining system 2.7. Perhaps py2app could more robustly check this? There were no messages about what was happening.